# How to add (Reverse) DNS entries in Cisco IOS?

Tags: dns, cisco, reverse-dns, cisco-ios

I've got a customer where the router needs to be replaced with a Cisco router.
The current router is a linux machine with webmin installed on it.

There's a BIND DNS server with multiple zones.

There's a zone called companyname.be with entries name-ip (address records).

There's also a zone called 192.9.200 (which is the local subnet) with entries address-name (reverse address records).

This configuration can be seen below:
[image]
[image]

I'm not sure why they need this but someone at the customer's company told me that it's necessary.

In the end the goal is to be able to ping by using a name rather than an IP.

Does someone know how to configure this in Cisco IOS?

I've been searching this for a while now but all I came up with is this link: http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/257-cisco-router-dns-server.html

I tried it but this only seems to create a host table on the router itself.
That hosttable is not used by the DNS.
(Can ping to domain name from router CLI but cannot ping to a domain name from a PC with that router as default gateway.)

Answer (score -1):

I've already found the answer here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dns/configuration/15-sy/dns-15-sy-book/Configuring-DNS.html#GUID-E4A67061-354E-4847-8F56-9A88446C7D30

```
R1#conf t
R1(config)#ip domain companyname.be
R1(config)#ip name-server 8.8.8.8

R1(config)#ip dns server
R1(config)#ip host computername1.companyname.be
```

And for the DHCP server to send the DNS server to DHCP clients:

```
R1(config)#ip dhcp pool pool_name
R1(dhcp-config)#dns-server ip_address_of_router
```

Now any host can ping computername1.companyname.be.